# Typescript move object back and forth

Tags: typescript, object, position

I am working on a typescript web game.

I need the object to move back and forth along Y-Axis.
[image]

So basically, the object starts at **coorY**, with speed of **dy**, its current coordinate is **Y**.

When current **Y** is less than **coorY**(10), it move towards right, when it is greater than **coorY** **+** **50** (60), it move towards left.

```
public Move(): void {
        this._dy = 1;
        this.dir = true;
        if (this.y > this.coorY + 50) {
            this.dir = true;
            console.log("Forth " + (this.y - this.coorY));
        }
        else if (this.y < this.coorY) {
            this.dir = false;
            console.log("Back " + (this.y - this.coorY));
        }

        if (this.dir) {
            this.y -= this._dy;
        }
        else if (!this.dir) {
            this.y += this._dy;
        } 
    }
```

But somehow the object moves very little, it looks like it is shaking, or just stuck at original position. How do I make it move back and forth?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove `this.dir = true;` from inside the Move function.

[Example](http://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#src=class%20Test%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20_dy%20%3D%201%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20dir%20%3D%20true%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20y%20%3D%2010%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20coorY%20%3D%2010%3B%0D%0A%0D%0A%20%20%20%20public%20Move()%3A%20void%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20this._dy%20%3D%201%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20if%20(this.y%20%3E%20this.coorY%20%2B%2050)%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20this.dir%20%3D%20true%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20console.log(%22Forth%20%22%20%2B%20(this.y%20-%20this.coorY))%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%7D%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20else%20if%20(this.y%20%3C%20this.coorY)%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20this.dir%20%3D%20false%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20console.log(%22Back%20%22%20%2B%20(this.y%20-%20this.coorY))%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%7D%0D%0A%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20if%20(this.dir)%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20this.y%20-%3D%20this._dy%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%7D%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20else%20if%20(!this.dir)%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20this.y%20%2B%3D%20this._dy%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%7D%20%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%0D%0A%0D%0A%20%20%20%20constructor()%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20let%20div%20%3D%20document.createElement(%22div%22)%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20div.innerText%20%3D%20%22Test%22%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20div.style.position%20%3D%20%22absolute%22%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20div.style.left%20%3D%20this.y%20%2B%20%22px%22%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20document.body.appendChild(div)%3B%0D%0A%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20setInterval(()%20%3D%3E%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20this.Move()%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20div.style.left%20%3D%20this.y%20%2B%20%22px%22%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%7D%2C%2010)%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%0D%0A%7D%0D%0Anew%20Test()%3B)